# Android: Date Picker using xml layout

Tags: android, datepicker

i have some problems in using the date picker from xml layout.

in my app when the user clicks a text view a custom dialog box opens. In the layout of the custom dialog box i am showing a date picker which i have place in my xml file. When it appears in the app i want a particular date to be viewed, for example as 01 Jan 1950. Every time it opens it is showing the present date only.

In my dialog box i have a set and cancel buttons. The Cancel button cancels the dialog box where as when i click the Set button i want the current date to be stored to a String.

In another activity of my app in a custom dialog box i want to show a date picker only with the year columns, i dont need the date and month columns. How to get it, please help me friends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing any code, I just can propose you to use the method **init** from the DatePicker class. Check this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#init%28int,%20int,%20int,%20android.widget.DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener%29) but basically, in your activity do something like:

```
myDatePicker = (DatePicker)findViewByID(...);
myDatePicker.init(myYear,myMonth,myDay, myOnDateChangedListener);
```